# How do I check if a value is present within my array? - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can one kindly advise me how i do check if my array includes a value.

- i have an array `attendees = social.attendances`
- i am trying to check if the `user = User.find(4)` is present within the `attendees` array

> Terminal

```
user = User.find(4)
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
 => #<User id: 4, email: "emma@gmail.com"> 


social = Social.find(10)
  Social Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "socials".* FROM "socials" WHERE "socials"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
 => #<Social id: 10, title: "How to successfully fundraise"> 


attendees = social.attendances
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<user_id: 10>, #<user_id: 4>, #<user_id: 14>, #<user_id: 9>, #<user_id: 6>]>
```

> i tried the below:

i tried the below in the terminal but no luck

```
 attendees.include?(user_id:4)
 => false 

attendees.include? "user_id:4"
 => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
user = User.find(4)
social = Social.find(10)

social.attendances.exists?(user: user)
```

Comment: Thank you @spickermann! this works perfectly in the views.  `<% if @social.attendances.exists?(user: current_user) %> #do something <% end %>`  how will i write this in the social.rb model -  would it be like this --------->`def attending?
    self.attendances.exists?(user: user)
  end`

Comment: figured it out! - thanks @spickemann!  social.rb `def attending?(user)
    self.attendances.exists?(user: user)
  end`     views/social/show.html.erb `<% if @social.attending?(current_user) %>
  #do something
<% end %>`

Answer (score 2):

These should work as well

```
attendees.include?(user) #always use parentheses with methods like this

attendees.select {|a| a.id == 4}.present?
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have an id of your model and you want to perform a check with a SQL query you can do

```
User.exists?(4)
```

Or, in a normal array object, you need the entire User object

```
attendees.include?(user)
```

or, with just the id

```
attendees.find { |attendee| attendee.id == 4 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need just check, you can write like:

```
!!attendees.find_by(user_id: 4)
#=> true or false
```

If you want to do it in Rails-style, you can use `present?`:

```
attendees.find_by(user_id: 4).present?
#=> true or false
```

Comment: thats very javascripty